# Differences between windows versions in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, syntax

I need to know if there are any syntax differences between batch in Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Batch heavily, but I haven't noticed any.

Comment: Run your batch file on them. Do you get an error or does something break? If so, come back and ask about that issue. This site is for specific questions related to code or a programming tool.

Comment: I have not noticed any.  I have migrated from Windows 2003 Server, to Windows 2008 Server, to Windows 2012 Server and now I have Windows 2016 Server and I have not had a batch file fail yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 and 8 must be the same . In Windows 10 there are some new features and bug fixes. The differences are small (too small to call them syntax differences) but still exist.

1) [This bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284131/cmd-exe-parsing-bug-leads-to-other-exploits) (the question is closed but I think still readable) for example caught the MS attention. This code will crash the command prompt on 7 and 8 ,but not on 10:

```
@echo off 
rem do not set new lines at the end or you'll break the breaker
echo combobreaker |(>^
```

2) On windows 10 this will enable the ["debug" mode](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=54448#p54448) of the command prompt (rather bug mode..) while will not work on win7/8

```
break&(:#)
```

For win7/8 you'll have to use a sequence of 256 opening brackets.To exit the "debug" mode on win10 you can use a sequence of 256 `@` symbols ,but this will not work on win7/8.

4) Windows 10 console could have a different behavior depending if "Legacy console" is [***used or not***](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8352):

[image]

5) Windows 10 [supports VT-100 escapes](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2016/02/04/Windows-10-TH2-(v1511)-Console-Host-Enhancements)

6) Two new environment variables: FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING ,FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING - probably related to the edge browser

Not sure if these counts.

7) A new command line tool - **clipup** - which I have no idea what is used for.

8) Some new [WMI](https://www.404techsupport.com/2014/12/07/windows-10-build-9879-introduced-new-wmi-classes/) classes that can be accessed with WMIC command.

There are also new enhancements in the .NET classes and in the powershell ,but these are already too far from command prompt.

Comment: Point 1 link leads to _page not found_

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: it's deleted, but visible *once you have enough reputation*

Comment: @Stephan yes, I doubt however that Andrei Filip have enough reputation to see it :)

Comment: @stephan, I fully agree. My point is there is a link on the answer which leads to _page not found_ for low rep users, so why link it if it will not be seen? :)